# How to get values back to multiple text boxes as i inserted from multiple text boxes to single value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing an application which gets the Mobile no. through a multiple text boxes, 1 digit per text box, I have inserted values successfully by cancatination, now the problem is that how I can get these values back to multiple text boxes 1 digit per text box?

```
    private[enter image description here][1] void button2_C[enter image description here][1]lick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string btn2 = ""+textBox1.Text+ textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox5.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text + textBox9.Text + textBox10.Text + textBox11.Text + "";
        label1.Text = btn2;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //??
    }
```

Comment: FIrst learn to name your controls properly. It will help you and especially people you ask for help. *button2* or *textBox9* aren't understandable, though here it doesn't matter much. As for the problem, if the boxes all have one character you can go through the string and put each character to their respective boxes. Substring may be helpful.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot man, you make my life easy... Thanks  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a bit like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = yourConcatString[0].ToString();
   textBox2.Text = yourConcatString[1].ToString();
   //... and so on
   textBox11.Text = yourConcatString[10].ToString();
}
```

Why does it work?

Well, a string can be thought of as an array of `char`

If you index a string like this: `myString[7]` you'll get the 8th (remember- indexing is 0 based) char

```
string myString = "abcdefghijklmno";
char theEighth = myString[7]; //variable theEighth now contains 'h'
```

You then only need to turn the `char` into a string in order to assign it to a textbox Text property. `.ToString()` on a char will turn the char into a string:

```
char c = 'a';
string s = c.ToString(); //s now contains "a"
```

The only thing you have to remember in your code is that you concatenate into `btn2` but that variable is only existing inside the scope of the `button2_Click` method. You cannot access it in `button1_Click`. You'll have to put a class-wide variable if you want to access it in both methods

Please name your buttons/textboxes before you double click on them to start adding events etc, otherwise your code will fill up with meaningless controlnames like `comboBox27` - "hmm, is that the city, or the country combo? hmm..."